# Reposition UIActionSheet on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiactionsheet

I have a `UIActionSheet` which appears as a `UIPopoverController` on the iPad. I am trying to show it from a `UIButton` by using:

`[self.exampleActionSheet showFromRect:self.exampleButton.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];`

What I am trying to do now is to reposition this `UIActionSheet` on orientation change. But when I use the above code to reposition after the screen has rotated, it doesn't do so. Can anyone tell me how to do this properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better workflow would be:

1. Dismiss actionsheet when a rotation occurs
2. Calculate the new rectangle where it should be presented from
3. Present a **new** actionsheet from the new rectangle

Comment: Hmm. I thought of this, but it felt like a hack and wondered if there was a cleaner way to do this. Looks like I have no choice. Thanks for the answer though. :)